# how to make turtle leave the same color of trail on patches as that of its own color?

Tags: netlogo

How can I change the pcolor of patch as that of the color of turtle in netlogo?

I tried this, and it's not working:

```
set pcolor [color of rovers]
```

rovers is the agent breed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then it's simply:

```
set pcolor color
```

This tells the rover to change the `pcolor` of the patch it is standing on to be the same as its own color.

I'm assuming this is already in a context where you have `ask`ed the rovers. If that's not the case, then you need:

```
ask rovers [
  set pcolor color
]
```

Comment: Thanks :D, it seems so simple now. and it worked. :D